# Network Adapter just disappeared

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure

This morning I turned on my Computer and I didn't have an Internet connection. Checking the Network Center on Windows, it said there is no cable in the device. I replugged it, thinking that it is probably just some power issue. It didn't recognize the cable, so I tried a different, brand new one which came with the router *( There are no chew marks from my cats on both cables )*. After it still didn't recognize it, I turned the device off via Windows. Then it disappeared completely. Since that, I am unable to recover it.

What I have done so far:

- Uninstalled Drivers
- Ran CCleaner
- Turned it off in the BIOS
- Saved BIOS Settings
- Turned PC off after Windows came up for 2 minutes
- Turned the network device on again
- Saved BIOS Settings
- Launched Windows
- Reinstalled Drivers

All this didn't help. I fear this might be a hardware issue? It is an onboard Realtek LAN Module. My mainboard is a [758GM-S3 from ASROCK](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/785GM-S3/?cat=Specifications). I switched to WLAN now, but should I worry about my mainboard and did I oversee any steps I could take to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried cold boot?

My method for a cold boot (mileage may vary):

1. Shut down the PC
2. Disconnect the A/C Power
3. Press the power button to dissipate residual power
4. Wait for 5-10 minutes
5. Reconnect the A/C
6. Test

Comment: Tried it, no difference. The network device is still missing. It is also not in the device manager and a scan cannot bring it up.

Comment: Have you installed any new software recently that may have affected it?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of. I installed Diablo 3 last week and SWTOR a month back. Normally I don't install Software often. I used WLAN a long time because I shared Internet with my neighbor and the LAN device was deactivated a long time, maybe that damaged it? Idk, shouldn't be a problem normally.